# How to bell curve

Tags: statistics

My mom is a teacher, and her kids failed a test.

Suppose that her class had a mean of $x$.

How would she be able to curve a the marks such that:

1) The mean is 60

2) No mark exceeds 100%

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the question is about. If you have a sample of values $x_i$ with mean $\bar{x}$, you can apply an affine transformation $y=ax+b$ to obtain a mean $\bar{y}=60$ and a maximal value $y_\text{max} <100$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the scores are $S_1,..,S_n$, 
then  $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nS_i=x$$ 
and $$\max(S_1,...,S_n)=M$$

Let $T_i=aS_i+b$ for $i=1,..,n$; 
then $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nT_i=ax+b$$
and $$\max(T_1,...,T_n)=aM+b$$

This gives 2 equations
$$\begin{cases}
ax &+& b &=& 60 \\
aM &+& b &=& 100
\end{cases}$$
for two variables $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Note that the original question doesn't say the maximum score has to be 100, just that the maximum score should not exceed 100. If that's the case, a simple score shift by a constant ($\bar x + c$) might be sufficient.